# When did Artificial Intelligence research first start?

Tags: research, history, ai-field

When did research into Artificial Intelligence first begin?  Was it called Artificial Intelligence then or was there another name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The earliest research into thinking machines was inspired by a confluence of ideas that became prevalent in the late 30s, 40s and early 50s (e.g. [formal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic), automata, [robots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot)). Although the [Turing test](https://academic.oup.com/mind/article/LIX/236/433/986238) was proposed in the 1950s by [Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing), the work culminated back in the 1940s in the invention of the programmable digital computers, an abstract essence of mathematical reasoning. These ideas were inspired by a handful of scientists from a variety of fields who began seriously considering the possibility of building an electronic brain. [The field of artificial intelligence research was officially founded as an academic discipline in 1956 during the Dartmouth workshop](https://ojs.aaai.org//index.php/aimagazine/article/view/1904).

However, the concept of artificial beings is not new and it's as old as the Greek myths of Hephaestus and Pygmalion, which incorporated the idea of intelligent robots (such as *Talos*) and artificial beings (such as *Galatea* and *Pandora*).

See the following articles at Wikipedia for further details:

- [Artificial intelligence (AI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence#History)
- [History of artificial intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_artificial_intelligence)
- [Timeline of artificial intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_artificial_intelligence)